# Slider on barchart

Tags: highcharts, slider, bar-chart

With Highcharts I realized a barchart. This one show the number of documents per year.
To select one or more dates, use the slider located below the graph.
I managed to put it in place.
However, I can not link it to the chart.
Here, if you put the first cursor on 2000 and the second on 2003, he would have the graph should shows only the dates 2000, 2001, 2002, and 2003.

Can you help me to do this please ?

Here is my HTML/PHP code :

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>

<div style="margin: 20px 0px 0px 60px">
  <!--
  The "oninput" attribute is automatically showing the value of the slider on load and whenever the user changes the value.
  Since we are using a category x-axis, the values are between 0 and 12. For this example, I'm adding your base year (2004) 
  to the output value so it shows a label that's meaningful to the user. To expand this example to more years, set your max value
  to the appropriate value and the base year to wherever you plan to start your chart's data.
  -->
     <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#slider-range" ).slider({
      range: true,
      min: 1960,
      max: 2016,
      values: [ 1960, 2016 ],
      slide: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#amount" ).val( ui.values[ 0 ] + " - " + ui.values[ 1 ] );
      }
    });
    $( "#amount" ).val( $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0 ) +
      " - " + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 1 ) );
  } );
  </script>


<p>
  <label for="amount">Year(s):</label>
  <input type="text" id="amount" readonly style="border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;">
</p>

<div id="slider-range"></div>
</div>
```

And here is my JS code :

```
$(function () {
  $('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
      type: 'column',
      zoomType: 'x'
    },
    colors:[
      '#d8d826'
    ],
    legend:{
      enabled:false
    },
    title:{
      style:{
        fontSize:'0px'
      }
    },
    subtitle:{
      style:{
        fontSize:'0px'
      }
    },
    xAxis: {
        // NOTE: There is an interesting bug here where not all labels will be shown when the chart is redrawn.
      // I'm not certain why this is occuring, and I've tried different methods to no avail. I'll check with Highcharts.
      categories: ['1960','1961','1962','1963','1964','1965','1966','1967','1968','1969','1970','1971','1972','1973','1974','1975','1976','1977','1978','1979','1980','1981','1982','1983','1984','1985','1986','1987','1988','1989','1990','1991','1992','1993','1994','1995','1996','1997','1998','1999','2000','2001','2002','2003','2004','2005','2006','2007','2008','2009','2010','2011','2012','2013','2014','2015','2016'],
      tickmarkPlacement: 'on', tickInterval: 1,
      minRange: 1   // set this to allow up to one year to be viewed
    },
    yAxis: {
      min: 15,
      title: {
        text: 'Number',
        style:{
          fontSize:'0px'
        }
      }
    },
    tooltip: {        
      shared: false,
      useHTML: true
    },
    plotOptions: {
      column: {
        pointPadding: 0.2,
        borderWidth: 0
      }
    },
    series: [{
      name: 'data by year',
      data: [49.9,83.6,48.9,69.1,83.6,40.9,69.9,83,28.9,40.9,81.6,24.9,46.4,49.9,83.6,48.9,69.1,83.6,40.9,69.9,83,28.9,40.9,81.6,24.9,46.4,49.9,83.6,48.9,69.1,83.6,40.9,69.9,83,28.9,40.9,81.6,24.9,46.4,49.9,83.6,48.9,69.1,83.6,40.9,69.9,83,28.9,40.9,81.6,24.9,46.4,49.9,83.6,48.9,69.1,50]
    }]
  });  
});
```

You could see the result on : https://jsfiddle.net/uvat8u05/20/

Comment: You can put jQuery o your slider inside chart load event callback function, then use setExtremes for setting new extremes: https://jsfiddle.net/uvat8u05/22/

Comment: Great ! Thank you !

Comment: Happy to read that my example worked for you. I have posted it as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple solution for your problem is to add jQuery responsible for your slider inside load event callback function of your chart, and use setExtremes for setting new extremes on slide:
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.setExtremes

```
function(chart) {

    $("#slider-range").slider({
      range: true,
      min: 1960,
      max: 2016,
      values: [1960, 2016],
      slide: function(event, ui) {
        $("#amount").val(ui.values[0] + " - " + ui.values[1]);
        chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(ui.values[0] - 1960, ui.values[1] - 1960)
      }
    });
    $("#amount").val($("#slider-range").slider("values", 0) +
      " - " + $("#slider-range").slider("values", 1));

  }
```

Here you can find live example how it can work: https://jsfiddle.net/uvat8u05/22/

Regards,

Comment: Oh I am very sorry, I have another question please.
the graph is updated when you change the cursor, but how to make for the cursor to be updated when you select directly on the chart.
For example, if you select on the graph: 2000 -> 2003, then it would have 1 cursor starts on 2000 and the 2nd 2003.
Could you help me please ?

Comment: You may use afterSetExtremes in this case. Look at this example: https://jsfiddle.net/uvat8u05/27/

Comment: Cool, it is perfect ! Thank you !

Comment: That's very useful example, I am just trying to change it for y-Axis, but it does not seem to be working properly.  Can you have a look please https://jsfiddle.net/rishad/nck64xrb/

Comment: Also why does it change on the step of 10?